# Git pathspec error Related To Serialized Items on Disk

Tags: serialization

I am unable to commit any changes in Git due to an issue with my serialized items:

```
fatal: pathspec 
'solutions/SomeCustomer/src/Mysolution/serialization/System/Things/Data Access/Value Accessor Sets/Providers/xConnect/xConnect Addresses Facet Value Accessor Set/xConnect Others Property Value Accessor.yml' 
did not match any files
Completed with errors, see above.
```

This follows a wall of errors:

[image: Wall of errors during staging]

This occurs as soon as I try to stage my changes. I recently added items to Sitecore and pulled them via Sitecore Serialization CLI successfully.

I am using Sourcetree as my GUI. Sitecore 10.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not very obvious, this is caused by file paths being too long (which corresponds to my recent item additions under existing paths). This can be confirmed via shell commands in a Git terminal.

Run `git status` in a terminal session.

This returns a lot of data, but if you scroll to the top, just after the command was executed, in my case I saw this:

> warning: could not open directory 'solutions/MyTHing/src/MyTHing.Connector.MyTHing/serialization/System/MyTHingCustomer Tenant/Tenant Settings/Providers/xConnect/Filter Expressions/Contact Filter Expressions/Filter Contacts with non-empty Segments/': Filename too long
> warning: could not open directory 'solutions/MyTHing/src/MyTHing.Connector/serialization/System/MyTHingCustomer Tenant/Value Mapping Sets/MyTHingto xConnect Contact Mappings/MyTHingAddress to xConnect Other Addresses/': Filename too long

*(intentionally obfuscated a bit)*

The fix is to update the serialization settings. In your root, or close to it, you should have a `sitecore.json` file. In here, you can modify or add the `defaultMaxRelativeItemPathLength` property:

```
{
  "$schema": "./.sitecore/schemas/RootConfigurationFile.schema.json",
  "modules": [
    "src/*/*.module.json"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.Publishing@4.0.0",
    "Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.Serialization@4.0.0",
    "Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.ResourcePackage@4.0.0"
  ],
  "serialization": {
    "defaultMaxRelativeItemPathLength": 100,
    "defaultModuleRelativeSerializationPath": "serialization",
    "removeOrphansForRoles": true,
    "excludedFields": []
  }
}
```

In my case, surprisingly the value was `200` to start and I was only able to solve my issues by dropping it all the way to `100`. I also deleted the existing folders that had the issues and then re-pulled from Sitecore to populate them fresh. This results in some strange looking folders:

[image: Sitecore Shortened Folders]

However, this is normal and is Sitecore Serialization's way of truncating paths to fit the max length requirement.

**One final note:** this can result in a substantial commit for what may be a simple change, so I would personally recommend starting with this value lower (like 100). [Sitecore recommends 100-200](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/101/developer-tools/configure-the-maximum-relative-item-path-length.html) but 200 is far too high once you start nesting items.